# Counting the length of faces of a particular type of graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

So let's have a graph $A$ with only two vertices $u$ and $v$, and only one edge $e=(u,v)$ between them so $A$ is simple. By Euler's formula, $A$ has only one face and its length $l=2e(G)=2$. But $A$ has only one edge as we assumed, and isn't the path $u$-$v$ enough to bound it?

Attached picture has a slightly more complicated example: [image] As I wrote, $G$ has two faces: one is the triangle $v_2v_3v_4$, and the other is the outer face of length $5$. Similar to the one-edge graph $A$ above, I can't see why the $4$-edge walk, $v_{1}v_{2}v_{3}v_{4}v_{2}$, is not enough to bound the outer face.

I am afraid that I might have misunderstood the definition of a face, but I can't see how. Thank you for your help and I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Doesn't the bounding path have to be closed?

Answer (score 1):

I ussualy work with degree of faces, rather than length. But the issue is the same. See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872960/counting-the-degrees-of-a-face-in-planar-graph) for exemple.

The edge $v_1v_2$ must be accounted for 2. In general, you should see each edge as having two "*sides*". If the two are required to bound the face, you should double count the edge.